# How do I bundle electron app for Microsoft's windows using GNU/Linux

Tags: windows

I have a GNU/Linux OS (linuxMint) and I have to create a desktop app with electron for Microsoft's Windows OS. I need to know how to bundle the app in Gnu/Linux.

---

The following should be moved to another question

<del>I need to know how to store user credentials using electron-store and use it in different html files, with script tags. e.g. user details (name,email,....data). Using only electron-store without going to an external database and fetching from there.</del>

Comment: This looks like two questions: You can ask as many questions as you like, but only one question per question. Please edit, and create a new question for the 2nd question.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened?